# SFTP Add-on/Extension for SSIS to pull file from SFTP in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015

Trying to create an ETL process in SSIS using Visual Studio 2015 express to pull .csv files from an SFTP. Came across an add-on for older Visual studio versions but wasnt able to locate an 'SFTP Task' for VS 2015. IS there one that exists?

Here is what I found for older versions of VS:
https://ssisextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: How about a powershell task that pulls the csv files from the sftp instead an ssis package?...you can automate the task using the Task Scheduler...

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar on Script Tasks, it is not particularly hard to code a custom task for reuse but overkill for me

Using SSH.Net from nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET)

My working code is for upload instead of download, but it should get you started:

```
    using Renci.SshNet;
    using System.IO;

    ...

        string src = ...;
        string dst = ...;
        string host = ...;
        int port = ...;
        string user = ...;
        string pwd = ...;

        using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, user, pwd))
        {
            client.Connect();
            client.ChangeDirectory(@"Test");
            FileStream srcFile = new FileStream(src, FileMode.Open);
            client.UploadFile(srcFile, dst);
        }
```